# Angular2 Ionic with socket.io : unresolved function io

Tags: angular, socket.io, ionic2

socket.io is included as follows:

```
    <body>

      <ion-app></ion-app>

      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.8/socket.io.js"></script>
      <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
....
...
</body>
```

IN the service:

```
import '..';

@Injectable()
export class ApiEndpoint {
  public socket: any;

  constructor() {
    this.socket = io(remote);  <-- ERROR Cannot find name 'io'.
  }
}
```

How do I deal with this error ? Btw this is a COMPILE-TIME error ONLY.
Apparenlty the program runs fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an ambient declaration (called *io*) in order to avoid that compile-time error:

```
import '..';

// Prevent compile-time errors
declare var io;

@Injectable()
export class ApiEndpoint {
  public socket: any;

  constructor() {
    this.socket = io(remote);  <-- ERROR Cannot find name 'io'.
  }
}
```

The `declare` keyword is used for ambient declarations where you want to define a variable that may not have originated from a TypeScript file.